# websphere application server license?

Tags: websphere

Hi I am using IBM **Websphere application Server 7.0** trial version and the priod was expired. So please let me know how to get the licensed version for the same?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trial license can't be renewed. If you're using WAS for development and testing only, you might download developer's edition for free here: http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/appserv/developer/index.html .

Comment: What are the things that were eliminated from the previous one i had?

Comment: AFAIK, it has what ever you need from a development perspective. You don't loose anything in this edition.

Comment: Rt, it's just the WAS base edition. License-wise, at least as I understand it, your're limited to use it for development at developer's desktop only. Something more is here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ws/wasdevelopers/faq-wasdevelopers.html

Comment: Now there's a version called 'liberty' but, what is the compatibility of this? Is there a version compatible with WAS 8.5.5?

Answer (score 0):

You can only get a valid license through IBM, meaning once a you make a purchase and have a valid license you can proceed to download the full licensed product from Passport Advantage.

Comment: Unfortunately there is lots of incorrect information in your post. 1) You cannot prolong/renew trial version, and buying valid license will not help in that. You will need to reinstall from purchased version (downloaded via PassportAdvantage). 2) WAS for Developers is the SAME as WAS BASE, license is the only difference. 3) WAS CE will be soon withdrawn and unsupported, so for cheaper solutions better choice is WebSphere Application Server Liberty Core.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the answer just to remove all confusion. I wasn't specific enough about the licensing issue and downloading the product from PA. However, the rest of the information is something that's debatable and it's not necessarily incorrect. The IBM WAS for developers and IBM WAS stand-alone ARE considered different products for the simple fact that IBM won't support the WAS for developers on a production environment. If you consider it the same but it's a matter of license issue then I guess that's a more accurate way of describing it.